# PCB with IR for high speed detection

Tags: diodes

I am building a pcb board (18"L x 12"W) with infared diodes that will detect high speed @ a distence of about 1.00". Will the diodes pick up a speed of a metal object around 70 to 100 MPH?

Comment: How are you measuring speed?

Comment: Provide a detailed optical schematic and some specifications, please.

Comment: I am not measuring speed. I am sensing high speed movement to illuminate leds.

Comment: This project is very similar to a interactive light board, but with a much faster rate of speed at a range of 1.5" or less.

Comment: Your description leaves way too much room for interpretation. In which direction are the objects moving? What size are the objects? A small sketch would help a lot. I'm not familiar with "interactive light boards" so that doesn't really help either.

Comment: does the metal object emit IR radiation?

Answer (score 1):

It only depends on the focus of your optical path and reflected signal quality.

100 MPH = 1760 IPS so moving this speed over a distance of 1" is on the order of magnitude 1 millisecond which is well within the bandwidth at this short range.

Comment: Thank you Tony. That is want I needed to know. Much appreciated!